# How to fix AttributeError: 'GraphWin' object has no attribute 'yUp'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have installed graphics.py from https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/#description and am using Jupyter notebook to write my code. I have also copied the graphics.py in the same folder path(where my jupyter notebook belongs) as where i am writing my code. Why am I getting this attribute error?

I have tried using dir() method to find out all the attributes in the object GraphicWin object and it does not show yUp in it. My Jupyter notebook directory is D:\JSC\Scripts and in the same directory I created a graphics folder and copied the graphics.py library from D:\Python\Lib\site-packages

```
from graphics import *

print(dir(GraphWin))

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Face', 200, 150) # give title and dimensions
    win.yUp() # make right side up coordinates!

    head = Circle(Point(40,100), 25) # set center and radius
    head.setFill("yellow")
    head.draw(win)

    eye1 = Circle(Point(30, 105), 5)
    eye1.setFill('blue')
    eye1.draw(win)

    eye2 = Line(Point(45, 105), Point(55, 105)) # set endpoints
    eye2.setWidth(3)
    eye2.draw(win)

    mouth = Oval(Point(30, 90), Point(50, 85)) # set corners of bounding box
    mouth.setFill("red")
    mouth.draw(win)

    label = Text(Point(100, 120), 'A face')
    label.draw(win)

    message = Text(Point(win.getWidth()/2, 20), 'Click anywhere to quit.')
    message.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-51db6b6503a5> in <module>
     35     win.promptClose(instructions)
     36 
---> 37 main()

<ipython-input-1-51db6b6503a5> in main()


        3 def main():
          4     win = GraphWin("Addition", 300, 300)
    ----> 5     win.yUp()
          6 
          7     instructions = Text(Point(win.getWidth()/2, 30),


AttributeError: 'GraphWin' object has no attribute 'yUp'
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace **win.yUp()** with **win.setCoords(0,0,200,150)**

Answer (score 1):

The setCoords() method subsumes the yUp() method. A little more complicated to use but there you go.